Can Salesforce LWC code be manipulated using client side JavaScript
I have an lwc code to return the list of records based on the user input. There is a @AuraEnabled apex method with dynamic SOQL query to return the records. I am constructing a map<string,Object> with [{'fieldName':'Value'}]
I am sanitising only the value with escapeSingleQuote method before passing it into dynamice soql query and not sanitising the corresponding field name which is from the javascript and do I need to sanitise the field names also because I am using it field name also in the dynamic SOQL query.
html:
<lightning-input fieldName='Name' label='Name'></lightning-input>
<lightning-input fieldName='Phone' label='Phone'></lightning-input>
<lightning-button name='search' onClick ='handleSearch'/>
</template>

js:
handleSearch(){
let userInput =[];
userInput = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').foreach(ele=>{
if(ele.value){
userInput.push({ele.Name.toString():ele.value});

}
});
getListRecords({userInputs: userInput}).then(result=>{
console.log('result--'+JSON.stringify('result'));
}){
}.catch(error=>{
console.log('error--'+error);
})

}

Apex Method
@AuraEnabled
getListRecords(Map<String,Object> searchFields){
String query = 'SELECT id from Account WHERE ';
for(String eachFilter : searchFields.keySet()){
String fieldValue = String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchFields.get(eachFilter));// sanitising the value as it is user entered input
query += ' '+eachFilter+'= LIKE \'%'+fieldValue+'%\ ';// not sanitising the eachFilter as its the fieldName and not user entered input. do I need to sanitise this too with escapeSingleQuotes method?
}
return database.query(query);
}

